# SQL show count result even if it's 0

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables:

table `professor`:

| id | name | is_female | department_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | c | False | 2 |
| 4 | d | False | 2 |
| 1 | a | True | 1 |
| 2 | b | True | 1 |
| 5 | r | True | 1 |
| 6 | q | True | 3 |
| 7 | w | False | 3 |

and table `department`:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | department1 |
| 2 | department2 |
| 3 | department3 |

I need to count professors by department but only the once that have `is_value = true`.
My SQL code looks like:

```
SELECT d.name,
  count(p.is_female)
FROM department as d,
  professor as p
WHERE p.department_id = d.id
  and p.is_female = 'True'
GROUP by p.department_id;
```

and is working just fine by in this case its only showing:

| name | count(p.is_female) |
| --- | --- |
| department1 | 3 |
| department3 | 1 |

What should I modify to make it show `department2` with count 0?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Why aren't you using proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select d.name, count(case when p.is_female = 'True' then 1 end) from department as d, professor as p
where p.department_id = d.id
and p.is_female = 'True'
GROUP by p.department_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the filtering from your where clause, this means you are excluding all rows that are not female.

```
select d.[name] DepartmentName, Sum(case when p.isFemale='true' then 1 else 0 end) FemaleCount
from department d join professor p on p.department_id=d.id
group by d.[name]
```